# Table 1 not giving correct p-values in R package

Tags: r, p-value

The p-value function given via the following R Help documentation is not giving me the correct p-values

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/table1/vignettes/table1-examples.html

```
library(table1)

pvalue <- function(x, ...) {
  # Construct vectors of data y, and groups (strata) g
  y <- unlist(x)
  g <- factor(rep(1:length(x), times=sapply(x, length)))
  if (is.numeric(y)) {
    # For numeric variables, perform a standard 2-sample t-test
    p <- kruskal.test(y ~ g)$p.value
  } else {
    # For categorical variables, perform a chi-squared test of independence
    p <- chisq.test(table(y, g))$p.value
  }
  # Format the p-value, using an HTML entity for the less-than sign.
  # The initial empty string places the output on the line below the variable label.
  c("", sub("<", "&lt;", format.pval(p, digits=3, eps=0.001)))
}


Table1 <- table1(~ mpg+disp+hp+drat+wt+qsec+vs+am+gear+carb | as.factor(cyl)
             , data=mtcars, extra.col=list(`P-value`=pvalue), render.missing=NULL, render.categorical="FREQ (PCTnoNA%)",
             topclass="Rtable1-zebra")
```

|  | 4 (N=11) | 6(N=7) | 8(N=14) | Overall(N=32) | P-value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **drat** |  |  |  |  |  |
| Mean (SD) | 4.07 (0.365) | 3.59 (0.476) | 3.23 (0.372) | 3.60 (0.535) | **0.00216** |
| **gear** |  |  |  |  |  |
| Mean (SD) | 4.09 (0.539) | 3.86 (0.690) | 3.29 (0.726) | 3.69 (0.738) | **0.016** |

```
kruskal.test(mtcars$drat, mtcars$cyl)

Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  mtcars$drat and mtcars$cyl
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 14.395, df = 2, p-value = **0.0007486**


chisq.test(mtcars$gear,mtcars$cyl)

Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  mtcars$gear and mtcars$cyl
X-squared = 18.036, df = 4, p-value = **0.001214**
```

**0.00216** given by the function and **0.0007486** given by the test should be the same number.

**0.016** and **0.001214** should also be the same number.

Does anyone have an idea of why the p-values given by library(Table1) and the "pvalue" function in R documentation isn't working? and how to fix it? Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: I think we will need a little be more context here. First, CRAN is the name we give for the website that stores all R's packages (most of them at least). I'm not aware of any tables in it, except perhaps under the documentation of an existing package.

Second, as far as I can see, table1 is just a function to make tables. The actual p-values are calculated by your own function. 

Finally your function has a mix of two tests, one kruskal-wallis and chi-square. I cannot be certain but I suspect the divergence could be from there.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Alexandra! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here, please be explicit about non-base packages), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Given your question, though, I suggest that your issue has nothing to do with `table1` so much as the statistic tests themselves. Please [edit] your question to (a) remove the `table1(.)` call and output; (b) add sample data (please use `dput(..)`, c.f. links above; (c) SAS code and output. Tangentially, do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly into a [code block].

Answer (score 0):

The p-value function in R takes the "Overall" column into account.  Had to run Table 1 without Overall, to get appropriate p-values, then edit the HTML code in order to include them in the Table 1 with the Overall column.